# Why is MB_CUR_MAX 6 instead of 4 for UTF-8? (Linux, glibc)

Tags: c, libraries, locale, unicode, glibc

`MB_CUR_MAX` is defined by glibc as 'a positive integer expression that is the maximum number of bytes in a multibyte character in the current locale.'

If I print the value I get `1`. I assume that this is because C uses the `C` locale by default, even if my system's locale is `en_US.UTF-8`.

If I add `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` to my program, which should enable using the environment's locale, then `MB_CUR_MAX` becomes `6`.

Now my question is, why 6? Isn't UTF-8 an encoding with 1 to 4 bytes per code point?

Comment: Interesting. Originally UTF-8 had 6 as limit, so 31-bits. Later Unicode (because UCS-2 to UTF-16) decided to push pull maximum unicode code points to 0x10FFFF, so maximum UTF-8 size (for unicode interchange) is just 4 bytes (and not all values are considered valid. No idea why such *relic* remained. [Note: the ISO associated/parallel with Unicode did the same: from 32-bit to ox10FFFF as maximum)

Comment: with more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52203351/why-is-unicode-restricted-to-0x10ffff

Comment: Thanks @GiacomoCatenazzi, your answer pointed me into the right direction, but I think it's not right to say that "6 bytes is 31-bits"

Comment: @SebastianCarlos 6 bytes in UTF-8 encoding represent 31 bits of “useful” information: 1 bit in the first byte (1111110x) and 6 bits per byte in each of the following 5 bytes (10xxxxxx).

Comment: @SebastianCarlos: right. it is formally correct, because it all depends on encoding, but it is for sure confusing. UTF-8 can represent any 31-bit number using 6 bytes. UTF-8 is not created to be size efficient, but to recover from errors (discarding eventually just the wrong character).

Comment: Got it. Thanks everyone.

Comment: This *feature* derives from this line: https://sources.debian.org/src/glibc/2.37-12/localedata/unicode-gen/utf8_gen.py/#L196 . I cannot find any comment on the reason (and all tests/examples uses modern 0x10FFFF as maximum value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#History), UTF-8 indeed needed up to 6 bytes until 2003, when RFC 3629 added some constraints:

> UTF-8 was first officially presented at the USENIX conference in San
> Diego, from January 25 to 29, 1993. The Internet Engineering Task
> Force adopted UTF-8 in its Policy on Character Sets and Languages in
> RFC 2277 (BCP 18) for future internet standards work [...]
>
> [The table above, labeled "UTF-8 (1993)" shows that representing
> code-points from U+4000000 to U+7FFFFFFF requires 6 bytes]
>
> In November 2003, UTF-8 was restricted by RFC 3629 to match the
> constraints of the UTF-16 character encoding: explicitly prohibiting
> code points corresponding to the high and low surrogate characters
> removed more than 3% of the three-byte sequences, and ending at
> U+10FFFF **removed more than 48% of the four-byte sequences and all
> five- and six-byte sequences.**

Comment: Maybe you can quote some lines from Wikipedia. Otherwise your answer can be counted as link only